# cx_Freeze: 'The system cannot find the file specified' error during build [win10] [PyQt4] [python2.7]

Tags: python-2.7, cx-freeze

I'm trying to create a .exe file from a python script (which use PyQt4 GUI and matplotlib). I'm using cx_Freeze version 5.1.1 for 64-bit windows with the following `setup.py`:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib

base = "Win32GUI"

includes = ["atexit"] 

buildOptions = dict(
    #create_shared_zip=False,
    #append_script_to_exe=True,
    includes=includes
) 

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable(script = "main.py", base = base)] # icon = "chart32.jpg")]
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name= "1ChPlotGUI",
    options = dict(build_exe=buildOptions), # {"build_exe": {"packages": ["matplotlib"], "include_files":["chart32.jpg"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "1 Channel Plotting app with GUI",
    executables = executables
)
```

after running

```
python setup.py build
```

in the cmd from the position of

```
C:\Users\Us.Er\Pyth-examples\Qt\UI-examples\ChannelplotGUI-to-exe
```

I have something like this:

```
running build
running build_exe
copying c:\users\Us.Er\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site- 
packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Win32GUI.exe -> build\exe.win-amd64-2.7\main.exe
copying 
c:\users\Us.Er\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\python27.dll -> 
build\exe.win-amd64-2.7\python27.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 23, in <module>
    executables = executables
 File "c:\users\Us.Er\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
 File "C:\Users\Us.Er\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.7.4.3348.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
dist.run_commands()
 File "C:\Users\Us.Er\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.7.4.3348.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
 File "C:\Users\Us.Er\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.7.4.3348.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
 File "C:\Users\Us.Er\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.7.4.3348.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
 File "C:\Users\Us.Er\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.7.4.3348.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
 File "C:\Users\Us.Er\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.7.4.3348.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
 File "c:\users\Us.Er\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
freezer.Freeze()
 File "c:\users\Us.Er\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 626, in Freeze
self._FreezeExecutable(executable)
 File "c:\users\Us.Er\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 232, in _FreezeExecutable
self._AddVersionResource(exe)
 File "c:\users\Us.Er\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 172, in _AddVersionResource
stamp(fileName, versionInfo)
 File "c:\users\Us.Er\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32verstamp.py", line 159, in stamp
h = BeginUpdateResource(pathname, 0)
pywintypes.error: (2, 'BeginUpdateResource', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

What is the possible solution for above problem?

**EDIT**
To be clear: I don't want to add any icon for now. I am happy with just a simple, working .exe
I have added the target in this way:

```
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable(script = "main.py", base = base, targetName="main.exe")]
```

I have tried to add

```
targetDir = "C:\Users\Us.Er\Pyth-examples\Qt\UI-examples\ChannelplotGUI-to-exe"
```

anyway, the return is:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'targetDir'
```

The main problem is as before - the error with last lines as:

```
h = BeginUpdateResource(pathname, 0)
pywintypes.error: (2, 'BeginUpdateResource', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

Comment: The setup script you've posted cannot be correct, you have  commented out code continuing on a new line at two places. Please post the exact code you're running to obtain the error message you've posted. Only guessing, possible caveats are: 1. the icon file cannot be found or cannot be converted to a valid `.ico` file, see [How to add an icon to a cx_Freeze executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54134269/8516269); 2. an issue with `targetName` or `targetDir` in the `Executable` call, see [Python cx_freeze 4.3.4: Setting targetName causes errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54134269/8516269)

Comment: Indeed, there was incosistency due to formatting and newlines here, on SO. Edited and cleared.  
I don't need a icon now, so this is why it is commented out. Next, I will try second option.

Comment: @jpeg There is some problem with second link from your comment: It brings the same webpage as the first link.

Comment: Here is the correct link: [Python cx_freeze 4.3.4: Setting targetName causes errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28542541/8516269), sorry and thank you for pointing at this error.

Comment: Also be careful with `\ `s in string literals, you might need to escape them using `\\ ` or to prepend a `r` to the string literal.

Comment: You could also try to find out more about the problematic resource by adding `print pathname` in your `win32verstamp.py` just before line 159 or by running your setup call in debug mode in an IDE and looking at the content of `pathname` where the error is raised.

Answer (score 7):

In my case the issue was solved by changing

```
'build_exe': 'build_folder'
```

to

```
'build_exe': './/build_folder'
```

This is because `open(pathname)` would work on the `pathname='build_folder\\executable.exe'`, allowing the code to advance during the check at the begginning of the **stamp** method, but `BeginUpdateResource(pathname, 0)` would only work on `'.//build_folder\\executable.exe'`

Answer (score 3):

> Solution

```
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'build_exe': './/build'
    }
}
```

**Note:** `.//build` here, `build` is the folder name where you want to build your project.

Comment: This was actually helpful for case where other build options are passed. Nested "build_exe" key complicates things making other responses not that straightforward to use.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to help of user **jpeg** I managed to successfully freeze the script.
To eliminate the problem with path I have added a line `print(pathname)` in `win32verstamp.py` before line 159.
The print statement worked fine showing the relative path to the newly made .exe file.
Despite showing the correct path, the error was still present. I went to the `stamp()` definition in `win32verstamp.py` and found a try - except block, and have inserted `print(pathname)` over there.
The part is:

```
def stamp(pathname, options):
# For some reason, the API functions report success if the file is open
# but doesnt work!  Try and open the file for writing, just to see if it is
# likely the stamp will work!
#print("Current path is " + pathname)
try:
    f = open(pathname, "a+b")
    f.close()
    print("Possible to open" + pathname) #<---line added
except IOError, why:
    print "WARNING: File %s could not be opened - %s" % (pathname, why)r code here
....
```

Since that the freeze was possible. (Not sure why tho, I'm happy to add some info if explanation is known)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue tying to freeze my PyQt5 app (using python 3.7 under windows 10) with the following message :

```
h = BeginUpdateResource(pathname, 0)
pywintypes.error: (2, 'BeginUpdateResource', 'Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.')
```

So I choose to use cx_freeze Sample provided as a first step.
(This samples are availables after cx_freeze installation under MyVENVpath\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\samples)
The very basic PyQt5 exemple was working, but my case was way more complex as I used several sub Python class I have developed.

I honestly **don't really understand why but I was able to make it work** So here is all modifications I have performed :

1. In setup.py identify sub python files

add my personnal packages and class like this :

```
include = ["PyQt5", "PySerial", "myclass1", "myclass2", "myclass3", "PandasModel"]
packages = ["PySerial", "myclass1", "myclass2", "myclass3", "PandasModel", "pandas","math"]
```

2. Use relative path in setup.py

   ```
   executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable(os.getcwd() + r'\..\..\MyFileName.py', base=base)]
   include_files = [(os.getcwd() + r'\..\..\CalibrationTool.ui', r'Inputs\GUI\CalibrationTool.ui')
   ```

The reason for "...." is to jump two directories higher level, as my python.exe is in sub folders VENV\Script\

3. Add python Files containing "Myclass1" at same level as setup.py.

Even if in my application, class files are in a subfolder Input\Packages\Myclass1File.py, I had to copy-paste it at the same level as setup.py. This way the include and package line of setup.py work and was able to generate the executable.

4. Last but not least,the terminal command
   I have no idea why but the only command who did suceed was:
   to use full path to the python.exe and full path to the setup.py with the "build" at the end.

   cmd:>C:\Folder1\Folder2\MyVENV\Scripts\python.exe D:\Folder1\Folder2\setup.py build

This finaly created the executable in a build folder under C:\Folder1\Folder2\MyVENV\Scripts\